# Recover mysql using data folder

Tags: mysql, restore, recovery, disaster-recovery

One of our MySQL servers died but somehow we were able to recover all the files from it. This server was a slave at one time however we stopped it being a slave so we could use it for housekeeping tasks and reports, etc.

Can someone tell me how to recover with this?

I now have these files and a backup of my.cnf

```
ll /root/home/recovered/mysql/
-rw-r----- 1 root root          117 Jun  1 09:30 rabney-relay-bin.000001
-rw-r----- 1 root root           26 Jun  1 09:30 rabney-relay-bin.index
-rw-r----- 1 root root 113055367168 Jun  1 10:42 ibdata1
-rw-r----- 1 root root   1073741824 Jun  1 09:33 ib_logfile0
-rw-r----- 1 root root   1073741824 Jun  1 09:33 ib_logfile1
drwx------ 2 root root         4096 Jun  1 09:30 mysql
drwx------ 2 root root        16384 Jun  1 09:30 production_copy
-rw-r----- 1 root root   3253518648 Jun  1 09:32 slowquery.log
drwx------ 2 root root         4096 Jun  1 09:30 test
```

I've been reading articles on Google regarding this but not sure how to do it yet.

Comment: Try it here http://dba.stackexchange.com/